# Automatically reference .h files in bash script

Tags: c, bash, unix

I am running a concolic analysis tool crest ( http://code.google.com/p/crest/ ) on the Apache source code. The usage for the application is:

```
../crestSVN/bin/crestc server/request.c
```

So for each .c file that exists, this command needs to be run. In order to speed things up, I went ahead and wrote a small bash script to loop through all of the .c files in a directory and ran this command on it. The problem is that many of the .c files have header files that they reference. If the header file wasn't found in the directory, then the crest command would crash while attempting to analyze the .c file.

To get around this, I wrote a small statement "export C_INCLUDE PATH="..... for various folders that include the .h files. This has worked OK and Crest is able to work pretty well on most of the files. However, there a few problems. I am sure that I have forgotten to include some of the directories for the .h files in the "C_INCLUDE_PATH" statement that I created. Additionally, I believe there are issues when different "include.h" files are located in a different directory. Using the above process, the wrong "include.h" file may be referenced, and thus lead to a problem when crest tries to run on a .c file.

My questions are:

- Is there a way for the correct .h file to be found and linked to the 
  .c file that I am trying to reference in a more automated fashion?
- What general suggestions do you have?

Here is the C_INCLUDE_PATH statement that I used.

```
[root@localhost dan]# export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/modules/http:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/include:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/srclib/apr/include:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/srclib/apr-util/include:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/os/unix/:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/server/mpm/worker/:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/mpm/netware/:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/srclib/pcre/:/home/dan/Downloads/httpd-2.2.14/srclib/apr/include/arch/netware/
```

Comment: You should probably get the include paths from the configuration scripts and makefiles.

Comment: You could create preprocessed source files with gcc's option `-E` (or `-EP`, if crest doesn't like #line directives).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that fills the whole exported variable by exhausting all the possible directories under the current one:

```
C=`find . -name "*.h" -print0 | xargs -0 -If | sed -e 's!\/[^\/]*\.h!:!g;' | uniq`
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=`echo $C | sed 's/: */:/g'`
```

It also takes care if you have spaces in path names